# F# Refactoring Tools

Tags: f#, refactoring

Are there any good refactoring tools for F#?

I did some searching on Google, but there doesn't seem to be any available.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Typed `F# Refactor` in Google and loads of relevant results appeared?

Comment: @OMGtechy Unfortunately, it's not quite that simple. There've been several independent attempts to build F# refactoring tools over the years, none of which really took off. There's been a recent push in the F# community to combine efforts and build a good set of refactoring tools that are IDE-agnostic so they can be used with VS, MonoDevelop/XamarinStudio, emcas, Sublime, etc., and this is where the new Power Tools extension comes in (see my answer).

Comment: when you dont have code in 10 files 500 lines long, but instead have 50 clear lines, refactoring help is much less needed. may be rename could be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the new [F# Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) ([Github](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools)). It provides a bunch of useful features for refactoring F# code, and it's gaining new features rapidly. If you there's a feature you want which isn't available, open an issue on Github about it.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a Rename refactoring added to [F# Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) very recently. You can find by searching for `f# power tools` in Tools|Extensions and Updates in VS 2012+. (See @Jack P's answer for more on that)

CodeRush templates and some select items such as duplicate line etc. work in F# but it's going to take lots of positive pressure to get much more (starting with not stealing Ctrl-Alt-F for invoking FSI).

JetBrains have [a spike called FSharper](https://github.com/jetbrains/fsharper) but no stated concrete plans.